# What is the meaning of $\mathbb{F}_q^{\times}$?

Tags: notation

What is the meaning of $\mathbb{F}_q^{\times}$? I've never seen the $\times$ being used in superscript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any ring $R$, its common to use $R^\times$ to mean the multiplicative group of units.

Comment: ...which in this case, where $R$ is a field, means the non-zero elements.

Answer (score 1):

It denotes the *multiplicative group* of the field, i.e. $(\Bbb F_q\setminus\{0\}, \cdot) $.